# Need RE to detect UTF-8

Tags: python, regex, utf-8

I have the following code

```
inf = codecs.open(inPath , encoding='utf-8')
outf = codecs.open(outPath, encoding='utf-8', mode='w')
old = u'’;'
new = u'’&#59;'
for line in inf:
    line = line.replace(old,new)
    asc = line.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')    
    outf.write(asc)
    # print asc
inf.close()
outf.close()
```

This (correctly) converts smart quotes and accented characters etc, into their html entity format, using the numeric format. It will convert

```
<p>Dreams like: “Someday I’ll travel to…; someday I’ll write a book;
```

into

```
<p>Dreams like: &#8220;Someday I&#8217;ll travel to&#8230;; someday I&#8217;ll write a book;
```

This is all correct.

However code further down stream, sees the `&#8230;;` in the middle, drops the double semi-colon and then complains that it has not got a valid entity. I can't change this code.

As you can see from my code, I have caught one case where an entity is followed by a semi-colon. I don't want to replace all the semi-colons in the source.

How can I detect a semi colon that follows a UTF-8 character with a code point > 127, so that I can replace it with `&#59;`?  Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is with the code that "drops the double semi-colon and then complains that it has not got a valid entity"; you should post that code, too; and I don't think that removing double semicolons from text is what one would call expected behavior.

Comment: I totally agree the downstream code is broken. It is either Amazon's code or Apple's - and they won't play ball.

Comment: So what is that code that you are calling? Perhaps the question is rather "Why does Apple's whatever API remove double semicolons from my text?" not a regular expression for finding UTF-8 characters with following semicolons

Comment: I'm just loading an epub file into iTunes and replicating to my iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Face Palm!

If I convert to htmlentites first, and then replace `;;` with `;&#69;` that solves my problem.

Note to self - consider WHERE you do things, as well as what to do!